# Error 401 of proper credentials with python Eve AuthToken

Tags: python, api, rest, eve

How can I do authentication and authorization in a REST WEB API in order to get token secret, so that I can make POST requests?

This WEB API already exists, I try just to implement it in my local machine (https://github.com/nipreps/mriqcwebapi). It's based on python Eve, I already tried POST request with Basic authentication &  Token authentication with curl, it returns the error message 401  of credentials.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V49PF.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxgba.png)
Hasnae

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and their linked pages, plus "[Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/128421)".

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.